# spring boot config client could not load configuration from config server using bootstrap.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-config

Spring boot config client could not load the configuration from config server.

**bootstrap.properties**

```
spring.application.name = eon-service
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>microservice-eon-service</groupId>
    <artifactId>microservice-eon-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>microservice-eon-service</name>
    <description>Microservice project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.5-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

**Errors:**

- Even the client is not started at all

  http://localhost:8080/
- Error on console:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

No spring.config.import property has been defined

Action:

Add a spring.config.import=configserver: property to your configuration.
If configuration is not required add spring.config.import=optional:configserver: instead.
To disable this check, set spring.cloud.config.enabled=false or
spring.cloud.config.import-check.enabled=false.

Comment: Have you performed the steps that the **Action** said?

Comment: Client Application is working fine when it has it's own local application.properties file. and config server is also fetch the configuration from local git repository. The issue came when I change the client **application.properties** file to **bootstrap.properties** and removing the configuration entry from local file e.i *bootstrap.properties*

Answer (score 0):

To use the legacy bootstrap way of connecting to Config Server,bootstrap must be enabled via a property or the spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap starter.The property is spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=true. It must be set as a System Property or environment variable.  [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/2020.0.1/reference/htmlsingle/#config-first-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

After expending too much time I found two approach to fix this issues -
Basically we have to make the value of **spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled** as **true** by default it is **false**. This was already mentioned in [Spring Cloud doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/2020.0.1/reference/htmlsingle/#config-first-bootstrap) but I didn't get this point at very first time. After finding the solution of this issue, the point of spring cloud doc has cleared.

**First Approach:** set the System environment variable in `@SpringBootApplication`class

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     System.setProperty("spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled","true");
     run(Application.class, args);
}
```

**Second Approach:** An entry of dependency into pom.xml, it make *spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```